# Can't access new variable in Aqua

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, flux

I am using Aqua, a website and user system built using Hapi/React/Flux. http://jedireza.github.io/aqua/

I have a new text field in AccountsForm.jsx called "job". It has correctly added to the db as seen below:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("569a9fdf9b4fbb060a3f956a"), name: { first: "Dylan", middle: "James", last: "Thomas" }, timeCreated: ISODate("2016-01-16T19:54:07.334Z"), user: { id: "569a9fdf9b4fbb060a3f9569", name: "daylightdylan" }, job: "Web Dev" }
```

During onDispatcherAction > GET_ACCOUNT_SETTINGS_RESPONSE in account/stores/Account.js I can see that it is setting the this.state values using the values from action.data., which contains "name" and "timeCreated" however my new "job" variable does not exist. Where do I define/add my new variable to action.data so that it is available? I am new to this and I am completely lost!

```
this.handleResponseErrors(action.data);
this.state.hydrated = true;
this.state.name = action.data.name; ////exists
this.state.job = action.data.job; ////does not exist
this.state.timeCreated = action.data.timeCreated;  ////exists
this.emitChange();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The fieldsAdapter in the API handler needs to be updated with the new variable that is to be added. For example:

```
var fields = Account.fieldsAdapter('user name timeCreated');
```

With new variable added:

```
var fields = Account.fieldsAdapter('user name job timeCreated');
```

The fieldsAdapter is a helper method that creates a fields object suitable to use with MongoDB queries.